# error Couldn't load type 'MyMaster'?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have multiple master pages  in my application. I made a custom type and inharit all master pages from it:

```
 public class MyMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private int myno;

    public int MyNo
    {
        get { return 50; }
        set { myno = value; }
    }

}
```

Basically myno is common in all master pages and master pages will be changing in content pages. To add this property I added in my content page:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName=MyMaster %>
```

Running on page I got subject error. Kindly guide me.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in a web *site*, you should typically put a derived MasterPage class in the application's App_Code folder. When VS compiles your site, classes in the AppCode folder are compiled into the site's namespace and available to the code-behind pages of the application.

If you're using a web *application*, you should be able to put the class file in the root of the site and reference it directly from the code-behind of any other page in the project, assuming all namespace references are correct.

Also make sure that your the `Build Action` for your class file is set to `Compile`. You can check this in the properties window by selecting the class file in solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.

Turns out the `MasterPageFile` attribute of my `Page` directive didn't match the `TypeName` in my `MasterType` directive.

In other words, I gave the TypeName for the wrong master page file.  Oops!

Here is a demonstration of the problem.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Departments/SomeMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="ExamplePage.aspx.vb" Inherits="Departments_ExamplePage" Theme="Default" %>

<%@ MasterType TypeName="Departments_SomeOtherMaster" %>
```